# Best way to put a border around ListView items

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have a ListView and I want to put a border around each item in the ListView.  Microsoft doesn't seem to have a system theme for the Border element.

What is the recommended way to theme the border so it looks good on Dark and Light theme?

Here is my ListView

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" Header="My Header" Margin="10,5,10,5">
                    <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="My Header" Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                               Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="TextBlock 1:"
                                               Style="{StaticResource ControlHeaderTextBlockStyle}" />
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding TextBlock1}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text=" TextBlock 2:"
                                               Style="{ThemeResource ControlHeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding TextBlock2}"/>
                                </StackPanel>

                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

****************Edit 1******************

I should have put this.  I want it in a Universal App targeted at WP8.1 and Windows 8.1, not just phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answers lead me to look at system brushes and I found ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush, which I believe will work.

Answer (score 2):

You probably just want the standard foreground color, right?  (dark for light, light for dark).  That would be the [`PhoneContrastForegroundBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769552%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneContrastForegroundBrush}">
```

Comment: +1 I like the contrastforegroundbrush much better, forgot about that one, in fact I think I'll just del my answer since it was more than the scope needed anyway. :)

Comment: PhoneContrastForegroundBrush is not found in Windows Phone 8.1, just Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1.